# What is a good way to handle non-mission-critical promise rejections

Tags: promise

In the application I am creating there are often promise rejections that are non-mission critical. I therefore want to carry on with subsequent code in the *finally* block. I have discovered that variables in the *then* and *catch* block are accessible in the *finally* block without the need to make them global. Would it be wise to use these variables in the *finally* block or is it inelegant?

```
function promiseFunction1(input) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (input === 1) resolve("resolution from promiseFunction1")
        if (input === 2) reject("rejection from promiseFunction1")

    })
}


var maininput =1 
promiseFunction1(maininput)
.then((result)=>{
    //ideal outcome
    resultCapturedInThen = result
})
.catch((error)=>{
    console.log(`Warning: soemthing bad happened, but let's carry on`)
    resultCapturedInThen = null
})
.finally(()=>{
    if (resultCapturedInThen)
    { 
        console.log(`result of promiseFunction1 in finally is ${resultCapturedInThen}`)
    }

})

CONSOLE OUTPUT
____________________________________________________________
results
**if maininput is equal to 1**
result of promiseFunction1 in finally is resolution from promiseFunction1
**if maininput is equal to 2**
Warning: soemthing bad happened, but let's carry on
```

Comment: Use strict mode and see it fail. No, this is a horrible practice.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's good to know this is not a good solution

Comment: As for the proper solution, why not just put that `console.log` in a normal `then` callback?

Comment: I should have been more clear. I want to use the resultCapturedInThen for further processing (in case successful). If not (if Catch) I can carry on processing without it. Now, that would make duplicate code in the Then and Catch, which is why I use finally. However in that case I want to access the result captured in Then, and that is not passed to finally in an elegant way. That was why I was using this inelegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use the `resultCapturedInThen` for further processing (in case successful). If not (if Catch) I can carry on processing without it. Now, that would make duplicate code in the Then and Catch, which is why I use finally.

No need to use `finally` for that. You can take advantage of promise chaining:

```
var maininput = 1 
promiseFunction1(maininput).catch(error=>{
    console.log(`Warning: something bad happened (%v), but let's carry on`, error)
    return null
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(`result of promiseFunction1 is ${result}`)
    if (result !== null) {
        console.log('Looks like success')
    }
})
```

The `then` callback receives the fulfillment value of `promiseFunction1`, or the return value of `catch` handler callback if the `promiseFunction1` rejects.